# Does Cull Obsidian have limb regeneration?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers-infinity-war, regeneration

In the initial fight between "the Children of Thanos" and Tony Stark, Dr Strange, David Banner and Wong, Wong opens a portal to a cold, snowy wilderness - presumably somewhere in the Himalayas since Wong would be familiar with the area and Cull Obsidian falls through, and when he tries to jump back through, Wong closes it and he has his arm severed at the elbow. At the end of the movie in the final battle, he accompanies Corvus Glaive and Proxima Midnight and fights Banner who is wearing a Hulk sized Iron Man suit and he has both arms again. Is this a goof by the writers, or does he have some power to regenerate lost limbs?

Comment: From sister site [How did Cull Obsidian's hand grow back in the battle of Wakanda?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/92683/how-did-cull-obsidians-hand-grow-back-in-the-battle-of-wakanda)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In the scene that you're referring to, his arm is now made of metal topped with a three-pronged claw. Clearly it's a prosthetic device to replace his lost (real) arm.

[image]

Comment: I went through it frame by frame after asking that didn't have good enough resolution to see that but it appears you are correct. I still want to know how he got there; recall Wong sending him through a portal to somewhere obviously far from NYC? The ship he arrived on didn't stop and pick him up, he came with The Maw, and that ship left direct to Titan with Dr Strange and Tony and Spiderman as stowaways.

Comment: @Pelagicide - Presumably he just got a pickup like they did in Scotland. Ask it as a separate question though...